# foreach laravel always puts lastest iteration object's property in post form as an argument to route

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send every post's id to the server when the user clicks on post's delete button, but in my code which has come below, when the user clicks on the delete button, The Latest post's id always is sent to the backend, How to solve it?

```
@foreach($allPosts as $key => $posts)
    .
    .
    .
<td class="filterable-cell">
<a href="{{ route('posts.edit', ['id' => $posts->id])  }}" class="btn btn-edit btn-edit-remove"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
<form class="inline" **action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $posts->id ) }}"** method="post" id="formDelete">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">  
<button class="delete-brand btn btn-remove btn-edit-remove border-box deletePage" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash top-3"></i></button>
</form>
</td>
 .
 .
 .
@endforeach
```

Comment: give me the result of $allPosts->pluck('id') before sending to view

Comment: @MahdiYounesi, As below come, it is the output of what you wanted:
Collection {#652 ▼
  #items: array:15 [▼
    0 => 16
    1 => 19
    2 => 20
    3 => 21
    4 => 22
    5 => 25
    6 => 27
    7 => 28
    8 => 29
    9 => 30
    10 => 31
    11 => 32
    12 => 33
    13 => 50
    14 => 54
  ]
}

Comment: Are you using a resourceful controller and is there a specific reason for @foreach($allPosts as $key => $posts) and not just @foreach($allPosts as $post) ?

Comment: @ColinBarstow yes, I need the $key for indexing the posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a resource controller you should be using the delete request.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.destroy',  $posts->id)}}">
    {{ csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('DELETE')}}
    <button class="delete-brand btn btn-remove btn-edit-remove border-box deletePage" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash top-3"></i></button>
</form>
```

Using this method you'd simply call your delete like so

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();
}
```

This works just fine for me.

You have id's a on your form; as these are Inside a foreach loop you will have multiple forms with the same Id. Which is going to cause you issues.

A good way around that is to append the posts id to your id  name e.g.

```
<form id="buttonID{{ $posts->id }}">
```

Also as it's a foreach it's good practice to use a singular name such as $post

```
@foreach($allposts as $post)
```

Comment: {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('DELETE')}} didn't help either. About this <button id="buttonID{{ $posts->id }}">, you want to say, I should handle this by JS?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: There is no need for js at all. You are simply deleting an entry from your database. You need to tell your database what entry to delete. If you are using a resource controller then everything I put will work for you. There's no need for anything extra or additional. My id statement was simply making light of the fact t you are giving a form an id inside a foreach loop. This means you will have multiple forms with the same id which will cause you issues. Why does your form have an id?

Comment: My apologies for stating @csrf I stead of {{ csrf_field() }}, i have become to acustomed to laravels newer blade directives.

Comment: The problem is that the latest post's id in the posts list page always is sent to the controller, $post->delete() in the controller deletes another post

Comment: Inside your delete method die and dump post dd($post); if you're using a resourceful controller it should dump the post instance that you triggered the delete on.

Comment: I clicked on post with id=16 but the following is the result of dd: 
    "id" => 62
    "title" => "lallallala"
    "is_active" => 1

Comment: Then you're doing something somewhere in your blade file that's doing this.just try this in your blade file. Comment out everything and just do What I put up there Inside a foreach @foreach($allPosts as $post) and see if it dumps the correct instance.

Comment: It Worked, Thanks :D

Comment: Excellent, crack on with your project and keep learning as you go!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have another $posts variable in your page or something like that. I suggest you to choose another name in your *foreach* like **$Post**

```
@foreach($allPosts as $key => $Post)
.
.
.
<td class="filterable-cell">
 <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', ['id' => $Post->id])  }}" class="btn btn-edit btn-edit-remove"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
  <form class="inline" **action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $Post->id ) }}"** method="post" id="formDelete">
        {{csrf_field()}}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">  
    <button class="delete-brand btn btn-remove btn-edit-remove border-box deletePage" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash top-3"></i> 
  </button>
 </form>
</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried as you said but unfortunately, It didn't work.